# Dismiss dialog after touch up

Tags: android, android-activity

I have imageview and I need to implement that when I press long click on it and keep touching the screen , show that image in custom dialog, and dismiss it when I touch up the screen !

Like preview image in **Secret** application

Comment: could you pls be more specific where do you want to touch to make the dialog dismiss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your own OnTouchListener to handle the long click and then show your image until touch event end.

You have to create your own view for dialog too because standard AlertDialog will end that touch event.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that standard AlertDialog end mt touch event

could you please provide code to create view for dialog ??